# Authorize.Net Java SDK Environment Not Set Issue

Tags: gradle, authorize.net

I getting Environment Not Set error with Authorize.Net Java SDK Version 2.0.1

> "Environment not set. Set environment using setter or use overloaded
>   method to pass appropriate environment"

Following line throws error :

```
CreateTransactionController transactionController = new CreateTransactionController(apiRequest)
```

Although I confirmed using debug point that environment was set properly.

```
ApiOperationBase.setEnvironment(Environment.SANDBOX);
```

Strangely enough, this happened when I copied the implementation code to **Microservice** from earlier **Monolith** implementation of my project. 
**( Same code is working on previous application)**

You can also find the reported bug below for same issue back in 2015. Although it was closed as the person who raised it used an alternative solution.

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-java/issues/74

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Reverting to back to version 2.0.0 worked. 
I upgraded back to 2.0.1 to confirm if this was specific to version but more strangely it started working with 2.0.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error.

In my case, the error was not actually with setting environment.

Please find my answer in the below link!

[Authorize.net Environment not set issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650812/authorize-net-java-sdk2-0-1v-environment-not-set-issue/60740806#60740806)