# Authorize.net Java SDK(2.0.1v) Environment not set issue

Tags: java, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net as a Payment vendor in my application. After getting form token from Mobile SDK, I am using their Java SDK in Backend to initiate Payment.

But I am getting the following issue while using `CreateAnAcceptPaymentTransaction` class from Authorize.net Java SDK(v2.0.1).

> *Environment not set. Set environment using setter or use overloaded*
>   *method to pass appropriate environment*

The controller object in the below line has the error.

`CreateTransactionController controller = new CreateTransactionController(apiRequest);`

I have already set the environment via the below piece of code

```
ApiOperationBase.setEnvironment(Environment.SANDBOX);
```

Tried to downgrade the version to `v2.0.0` but it doesn't worked for me.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind too is that Authnet is currently limited to JDK 1.8 - This can become an issue if you are trying to run their SDK with a newer version of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not actually with setting Environment.

You might have got an exception which is mentioned below.

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath
```

It was with a missing dependency in gradle file or Maven file.

Add these dependencies into your pom/gradle:

**Gradle:**

```
compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
compile('javax.activation:activation:1.1')
compile('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0')
```

**Pom:**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
</dependency>
```

Original Post can be found here [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)